# Scala / Joda - Joda DateTimeFormat not applying

Tags: scala, datetime, jodatime

I want to retrieve a date from the DB and preserve its format.E.g. `"20200406T145511.067Z"` When I try to parse it as a Joda DateTime, the format changes to `"2020-04-06T14:55:11.067+01:00"`. Because of this problem, I tried to explicitly state the DateTimeFormat that the Joda DateTime should return as, `"yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss.SSS'Z'"`, but it does not seem to apply. I want to return a `DateTime` object in the format that I expect (E.g. `"20200406T145511.067Z"`).

```
    val dateTimeFormat = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss.SSS'Z'")
    val itemDateTime = dateTimeFormat.parseDateTime(record.get("itemDateTime").asString)

    println("Neo4J: " + record.get("assetDateTime").asString) // Neo4J: 20200406T145511.067Z
    println("Joda: " + assetDateTime) // Joda: 2020-04-06T14:55:11.067+01:00

    val lastUpdatedDateTime = dateTimeFormat.parseDateTime(record.get("lastUpdatedDateTime").asString)

    println("Neo4J: " + record.get("lastUpdatedDateTime").asString) // Neo4J: 20200406T145511.383Z
    println("Joda: " + lastUpdatedDateTime) // Joda: 2020-04-06T14:55:11.383+01:00
```

**EDIT:** I have updated my code to return the correct type `DateTime`, but I now get an invalid format error -

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "20200406T161516.856Z" is malformed at "1516.856Z"
```

I don't understand why this is happening. Any help would be appreciated.

**Updated code:**

```
    val dateTimeFormat = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss.SSS'Z'")
    val itemDateTime = dateTimeFormat.parseDateTime(record.get("itemDateTime").asString)
    val itemDateTimeFormat = dateTimeFormat.print(itemDateTime)
    val lastUpdatedDateTime = dateTimeFormat.parseDateTime(record.get("lastUpdatedDateTime").asString)
    val lastUpdatedDateTimeFormat = dateTimeFormat.print(lastUpdatedDateTime)
    if (lastUpdatedDateTime.isAfter(itemDateTime) new DateTime(lastUpdatedDateTimeFormat) else new DateTime(itemDateTimeFormat)
```

Comment: It's what's currently used at work. We are looking to update in the future, but for now I need to stick with it.

Answer (score 1):

You can just parse with ISODateTimeFormatter

```scala
import org.joda.time.DateTime
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat
import org.joda.time.format.ISODateTimeFormat

// val inputDt = record.get("itemDateTime").asString 
// let's imagine we have a data as following:
val inputDt = "20200406T161516.856Z"
val dateTimeFormat = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss.SSS'Z'")
val itemDateTime = dateTimeFormat.parseDateTime(inputDt)
val parsedDate = DateTime.parse(itemDateTime.toString, ISODateTimeFormat.dateTimeParser());
println(parsedDate) // 2020-04-06T16:15:16.856Z
val result: String = dateTimeFormat.print(parsedDate) //NOTE: return type is String
println(result) // 20200406T161516.856Z
```

UPDATE:

Documentation [says](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html):

> Internally, the class holds two pieces of data. Firstly, it holds the datetime as milliseconds from the Java epoch of 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z.

What I understand from this sentence, regardless of your formatting it keeps as `Long` (internal state) and the representation of it for a client is can be different depending on the Formatter and Chronology.

What we can do, it doesn't what format it is in application level. We might need to return a specific formatted date, so we can convert it when we need, for example: returning a json for rest client :

```
val dateFormat = "yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss.SSS'Z'"
val dateTimeWrites: Writes[DateTime] = new Writes[DateTime] {
  def writes(d: DateTime): JsValue = JsString(d.toString())
}
```

Comment: The result you show here is the result I am trying to avoid. The result I want cannot contain hyphens, nor colons.

Comment: Ahh, I see. Then you need to call print from datetime format, going to update my anwer with ```val result = dateTimeFormat.print(parsedDate)```

Comment: I am trying to return it as type DateTime and I think that's where I'm having my current problem. If you have another look at my question, there is an updated section. I appreciate any help you can give me!

Comment: @Chris, I have updated the answer again with a bit point of view

Answer (score 1):

### A DateTime cannot and should not have a format

You can’t. You are asking the impossible. Neither should you want to.

A `DateTime` represents a date and time in a time zone. It hasn’t got, as in cannot have a format. You can have any format you like in a `String`. Only in a `String`, not in a `DateTime`. Just like you cannot have an `int` with a format. You can format your `int` into different strings like `18`, `0018`, `+18` and `0x0012`, but the `int` stays just the same.

This is good! Good practice in all but the simplest throw-away programs tells us to keep model and presentation separate. Your date and time belongs in your model, this is where we need your `DateTime`. How it looks, its format, is a matter of presentation. This does *not* belong in your model.

So when you read the date and time from the database, satisfy yourself with a `DateTime` object the way you are already doing and don’t worry about the format because it hasn’t got any. Whenever you need a string in the compact format you mention, format your `DateTime` into such a string using the same formatter.

### There’s a bug in your parsing

You didn’t ask this, but you should want to know.

```
    println("Neo4J: " + record.get("assetDateTime").asString) // Neo4J: 20200406T145511.067Z
    println("Joda: " + assetDateTime) // Joda: 2020-04-06T14:55:11.067+01:00
```

Please take a closer look at the date-times in the comments. They are not the same. The former is in UTC denoted by the trailing `Z`. Yes, that `Z` is an offset of zero from UTC. The latter date-time has the same hour of day and a different UTC offset, `+01:00`. So it designates a different point in time equal to 2020-04-06T13:55:11.067 UTC.

Your problem is hard-coding `Z` in the format pattern string by enclosing it in single quotes. *Never* do that. The offset needs to be parsed as an offset. Use `ZZ` in the format pattern string for that. In Java (because it’s what I can write):

```
    DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormat = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss.SSSZZ");
    String assetDateTimeString = "20200406T145511.067Z";
    DateTime itemDateTime = dateTimeFormat.parseDateTime(assetDateTimeString);
    System.out.println(itemDateTime);
```

Output when I ran in Europe/London time zone:

> 2020-04-06T15:55:11.067+01:00

If you want to preserve the offset from the string, tell your formatter so:

```
    DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormat = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss.SSSZZ")
            .withOffsetParsed();
```

> 2020-04-06T14:55:11.067Z

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, it's been very helpful. The datetime is stored as `20200406T145511.067Z`in my database, but I can't seem to remove the hyphens and the colons when trying to return it. Your solution has fixed my time zone problem, but I am struggling to find a solution for the unwanted characters. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: I don't know your database and cannot be sure, but it would seem to me that for storing into your database you should format the `DateTime` into a string using the same formatter, which will give you a string with no hyphens, and then store the string (if your database has a date-time type, there may be other and more attractive options).

Answer (score 0):

```scala
val dateTimeFormat = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss.SSS'Z'")
val itemDateTime = dateTimeFormat.parseDateTime(record.get("itemDateTime").asString)
```

What you're doing here is parsing a string with the `yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss.SSS'Z'` format into a valid `DateTime` object. To print the object's content with the desired format, you need to call `dateTimeFormat.print(itemDateTime)`

Comment: I want it the return type to be that of `DateTime` and not `String`. The print statements are just there to show the formatting being incorrect. I should have provided more details about return type.

Comment: I've added `new DateTime()` calls when I return the results, so I get the expected format. However, I still get a formatting error. I'll update the question.